# Does Meyers' singleton used with [[gnu::pure]] have UB?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Does the following code have an undefined behaviour?

```
[[ gnu::pure ]]
static const MyClass &myClass() noexcept
{
    static const MyClass s_myClass;
    return s_myClass;
}
```

According to [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes), the `pure` attribute is for functions which have no effects except the return value and this return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables.

On the one hand, this function does not have any observable effects other than its return value and it always returns the same value. So it is completely safe to optimise away multiple calls to this function. This is I think what the `pure` attribute is for.

On the other hand, this function needs to construct the `MyClass` object on the first invocation. This includes calling a `MyClass` constructor and setting an implicit *is-initialised* flag to true. This could count as an effect besides the return value (although it is not visible from the outside).

---

This code works on `gcc`, but `clang` optimises away the `MyClass` construction part and makes `myClass()` return an uninitialised object. A `clang` developer insists it is because of the undefined behaviour.

See this bug report: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36750 (note it says `gnu::const`, but using `gnu::pure` produces the same result).

Comment: `[[gnu:pure]]` has no effect under the [tag:C++] language.  You might want to add the compiler specific information.

Comment: @Yakk, Thanks, I have updated the question.

Comment: You can't "trigger an undefined behaviour". Undefined behaviour isn't an event, or action. We say that a program written in a certain way _has_ undefined behaviour; that is, its behaviour is undefined. Going further, whether a program has undefined behaviour is determined by the C++ standard, which has no knowledge whatsoever of `[[gnu:pure]]`. As such, you will need to alter your criteria to look for some other effect/result/symptom.

Comment: @VictorGubin: Answer in the answer section please

Comment: Would you be able to link to the discussion in which a clang developer claims there is "undefined behaviour" due to the use of this implementation-defined attribution?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't buy the dev's assertion that the constructor has side-effects. At all.

Comment: Related discussion at https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-10/msg00024.html .

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two potential issues with initialization of a static local variable.

[First](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4.sentence-2):

> If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration

This implies that consecutive calls to this function could very much have different behavior - the first throws and the second doesn't. That seems to violate the spirit and intent of `pure`.

[Second](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4.sentence-3):

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

This implies that the interpretation of the body must be based on intrinsic state of the function - there needs to be locking, etc. That also seems to violate the spirit and intent of `pure`.

Comment: What do you mean by the spirit and intent of `gnu::pure`? IMO, the intent of this attribute is to tell a compiler that it is safe to call such function fewer times than the program says.

Comment: @Kane: If the constructor throws on the first call but not the second, the behavior of the program _changes_ if the compiler elides the second call. Absent clarification from the GCC folks of this (clearly under-specified) attribute, I think this is the best answer

Comment: @Nemo: In my example, if the constructor throws, `std::terminate()` will be called (the function is annotated with `noexcept`), so there will be no second call. But even if there is no `noexcept`, I do not see any issues eliding the second call within the same try-catch block. But I agree that the main problem here is that the attribute's spec is not detailed enough...

Answer (score 5):

All we have to go on is the text of the gcc attribute `pure`, from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> pure
>
> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables. Calls to such functions can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These functions should be declared with the attribute pure. For example,
>
> ```
> int square (int) __attribute__ ((pure));
> ```
>
> says that the hypothetical function square is safe to call fewer times than the program says.
>
> Some common examples of pure functions are strlen or memcmp. Interesting non-pure functions are functions with infinite loops or those depending on volatile memory or other system resource, that may change between two consecutive calls (such as feof in a multithreading environment).
>
> The pure attribute imposes similar but looser restrictions on a function’s defintion than the const attribute: it allows the function to read global variables. Decorating the same function with both the pure and the const attribute is diagnosed.

This is less technical than a typical [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) standard text would be, but this is what we have to work with.

I'll lay out the tests I read:

- Has no effects except the return value
- The return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables
- Calls can be subject to common subexpression elimination/loop optimization like an arithmetic operator
- The hypothetical function is safe to call fewer times than the program says.

The core of this is eliminating *duplicate* calls, not *all* calls.

Examples of things that aren't pure:

- Infinite loops
- Depend on volatile memory or other system resource
- May change between two consecutive calls

Nowhere in this description does it say "you can eliminate the first call to this function" -- it says you can eliminate duplicate calls to the function.

Clang's "optimization" results in the body of the function never running.  The purpose of `[[ gnu:pure ]]` is to remove *duplicate* calls, not to eliminate *all* calls.  As such, clang is clearly in the wrong.

There are probably attributes you could call `pure` that would permit the optimization clang is doing, but `[[gnu:pure]]` is not that attribute.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation contains this note:

> Interesting non-pure functions are functions with infinite loops or those depending on volatile memory or other system resource, that may change between two consecutive calls

Since the static variable constructor and invisible *is-initialized* flag are both changing memory between function calls, it would indicate that the function isn't pure.

The documentation for `pure` also notes that it's similar to `const`. It doesn't explicitly say this under `pure`, but under `const` it says:

> Likewise, a function that calls a non-`const` function usually must not be `const`.

Since your function is calling a constructor which is not `pure` or `const`, it seems like it might violate the rules of the attribute. But see the comment below.

Comment: Although it probably makes sense that that calling a non-pure function breaks the pure function, using this wording to prove it is a real leap. e.g. the documentation also said that `pure` has "looser restrictions" than `const`, which you chose to ignore.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the documentation isn't clear on *why* there's a difference between `pure` and `const` so it's hard to say. I added more justification to my answer.